# How to flat array of objects which can contain nested objects in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a data with structure like this:

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    subObjects: [
      { name: 'a1', age: 10 },
      { name: 'a2', age: 12 },
    ],
  },
  { name: 'b', age: 23 },
  {
    name: 'c',
    subObjects: [
      { name: 'c1', age: 30 },
      { name: 'c2', age: 32 },
    ],
  },
  ...
];
```

So, the array contains an array of objects, some objects also contain nested level object `subObjects` which contains the same structure as parent. Overall some 1st level object in array can have maximum two levels of nest (like above example shows).

Now, I need to have an array that gather all names of objects from above array, something like:

```
[
  { name: 'a' },
  { name: 'a1' },
  { name: 'a2' },
  { name: 'b' },
  { name: 'c' },
  { name: 'c1' },
  { name: 'c2' },
];
```

This is what I tried:

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'a',
    subObjects: [
      { name: 'a1', age: 10 },
      { name: 'a2', age: 12 },
    ],
  },
  { name: 'b', age: 23 },
  {
    name: 'c',
    subObjects: [
      { name: 'c1', age: 30 },
      { name: 'c2', age: 32 },
    ],
  },
];

const arr2 = arr1.map((obj) => {
  return obj.subObjects ? obj.subObjects.flat() : obj.name;
});
console.log(arr2.flat());
```

But the output lost the 1st level object names for those who has nested objects. So, what is the best way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive `flatMap` to do it (with a little help from the spread oparator!):

```js
const arr1 = [{name: 'a', subObjects:[{name: 'a1', age: 10}, {name: 'a2', age: 12},]}, {name: 'b', age: 23}, {name: 'c', subObjects:[{name: 'c1', age: 30}, {name: 'c2', age: 32},]}];


const recursiveFlat = (arr) => arr.flatMap(
  a => a.subObjects 
          ? [{name: a.name}, ...recursiveFlat(a.subObjects)] 
          : {name: a.name});


console.log(recursiveFlat(arr1));
```

This will work with *any* depth of nesting.